# Trying to create sailsjs policy fails with hook "userconfig" error

Tags: sails.js, policy

I can not get policy in sailsjs to work.

I end up at the same place over and over

At simplest

1) I issued sails new testProject
2) I add folder policies under config
3) I added file under folder added isAuthenticated.js

```
A hook (`userconfig`) failed to load!

sails lift --verbose

info: Starting app...

verbose: Setting Node environment...

verbose: Please run `npm install coffee-script` to use coffescript (skipping for now)

verbose: moduleloader hook loaded successfully.

verbose: Loading app config...

error: A hook (`userconfig`) failed to load!

verbose: Lowering sails...

verbose: Shutting down socket server...

verbose: Shutting down HTTP server...

error: Error: Invalid module:function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
     return next();
   }
   else{
     return res.redirect('/login');
   }
 }
```

Comment: I found my problem.  I was putting it under config, however, I needed to put it in policies under api.

Comment: write it in the answer, with the source code